# Aligning a string with string.Format()

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I got a method which receives a message and a `Priority` enum and returns a formatted string.

```
private string FormatMessage(string message, Priority priority)
{
    return string.Format("*{0,-6}* - {1}", priority, message);
}
```

`Priority` has three possible values: `High`, `Medium` and `Low`.

I'm using `string.Format`'s alignment option so that the output would look nice. What I'd like the output to look like is this:

```
*Low*    - First message
*Medium* - Second message
*Low*    - Third message
```

However, what I'm getting is this:

```
*Low   * - First message
*Medium* - Second message
*Low   * - Third message
```

I understand why this is happening, but what I'd like to know is whether there's an easy (and correct) way to get the wanted output by using `string.Format` and without introducing any new variables.

Comment: Why not just concatenate the stars around the priority value... `"*" + priority + "*"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string.Format("{0,-8} - {1}", "*" + priority + "*", message);
```

Or, if you're feeling fancy:

```
string.Format("{0,-8} - {1}", string.Format("*{0}*", priority), message);
string.Format("{0,-8} - {1}", string.Join(priority, new [] {"*", "*"}), message);
```

Comment: don't forget to make the -6 into -8 :)

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do this by modifying the first parameter only somehow, as adding *'s to the second parameter makes it a bit confusing to understand what's going to be the eventual output.

Comment: Lester, unless you override `ToString()` on your `Priority` class/struct that's not possible, I fear. If it's an enum, then even less so (unless you create a wrapping class with implicit conversion operators and a custom `ToString()`). Format strings are hardly  Turing-complete or intended as general-purpose template engines.

Comment: Also, if you're too concerned that the string concatenation in the second argument masks the intent too much, then I'd say introducing a new variable is really the easiest way of making intent and behaviour clear.

Answer (score 1):

Could you enlarge the first column to 8 spaces?, if so ...

```
private string FormatMessage(string message, Priority priority) 
{ 
    return string.Format("{0,-8} - {1}", "*" + priority.ToString() + "*", message); 
}
```